# Linking C++ library in visual studio, error C2079

Tags: c++

I'm using visual studio for the first time in a project to use the GGPO library (https://github.com/pond3r/ggpo). I built it with visual studio using the install and got a .dll, a .lib and a .h. Following tutorials I saw, I included the .h which is recognised by visual studio and I added the .lib to the linker.

My project usually compiles without error but when adding this small part at the beginning

```
#include "ggponet.h"
int main()
{
    GGPOSession ggpo;
    GGPOErrorCode result;
    GGPOSessionCallbacks cb;
```

I get the following error:

```
error C2079: 'ggpo' uses undefined struct 'GGPOSession'
```

GGPOSession is the only element causing a problem.

I have tried everything I could find to try to link the .lib properly but nothing seems to work.
I have also linked SFML without problem so I don't understand why this doesn't work.
Looking at the "Build order" output, it seems the compiler doesn't even try to link to find the implementation of the GGPOSession struct which can be found in the lib.

Thanks for reading, any help is welcome!

Comment: It should be `GGPOSession* ggpo;`.

Comment: That's not a linking error, but a compiler error. Are you missing a `#include`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As 273K said, `GGPOSession* ggpo;` makes it possible to compile without error. I still find it strange given it doesn't follow the Programming Guide given with GGPO but I guess my question has been answered, thank you.